# Will erasing a parallel OS (using OS-uninstaller) free up the whole drive or do I need to adjust partitions? [Solved]

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I'm planning on removing windows 7 from my lenovo t500 and sticking with Ubuntu 12.04. I'll use OS-Uninstaller to do the job. I'm wondering if it will automatically delete the partitions and give all the space to Ubuntu or is there further tweeking required?

Are there any traps for the novice in undertaking this exercise? Is there a better way?

Comment: I think you need to resize the Ubuntu partition when you are done. Use gparted to do it on a live-usb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1615667 the space used by the NTFS partition where Win7 was, and any recovery partition as well, will not be automatically added to your Ubuntu partition, so you will need to do that after removal by booting from live media with Gparted, as suggested by Alvar above.